# Python: Return custom class in Pool Map function. "Error sending result: Reason: 'AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'picklable'")"

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, threadpool

Im using the `pool.map(...)` function of the Python `multiprocessing` package to parallelize some task.

```
class ReturnMe:
    def __init__(self, some_value: str):
        self.some_value = some_value

class ClassA:
    def run()
        num_cpu : int = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        pool = Pool(num_cpu)
        input_list: List[OtheCustomClass] = self.get_some_of_these_objects('someVar')
        # The next line causes an error
        returned_objects : List[ReturnMe] = pool.map(self.some_work, input_list)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def some_work(self, input_list_item) -> ReturnMe:
        helper = Helper()
        if helper.check(input_list_item):
            return ReturnMe(input_list_item.some_value)
        return None
```

This leads to the following error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[<....ReturnMe object at 0x0000028791CD3B70>]'. Reason: 'AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'picklable'")'
```

Why can't I return my custom class object in the map function?

Comment: Apparently `helper.check(input_list_item)` is false, so `some_work` returns `None`, instead of a `ReturnMe` instance.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Even if i replace `return None` with return `ReturnMe('Anything')` I'm getting the same error. If I always return `None` there is no error. So the error seems to be caused by the returned `ReturnMe(...)`.

Comment: What is `input_list`? What are the `input_list_item.some_value`?

Comment: It's a list of other custom objects. `input_list: List[OtheCustomClass] = self.get_some_of_these_objects('someVar')` Each of those objects has three attributes. To make the example as simple as possible I'm just using one called `some_value`.